# Как получить полный стек вызова функций в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, отладка, fopen

Как получить полный стек вызовов для приложения C++, разработанного с помощью Visual Studio? Я хотел бы иметь полный стек вызовов проекта, который использует fopen(), включая код в системных библиотеках (ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll и т.д). Насколько я понимаю подобный функционал доступен в IDAPro и WinDBG (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HZCg1gVPpw , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8oaEAPC84gc). Но вопрос в том, можно ли сделать похожее в Visual Studio?

Comment: ¿Ну а что помешало вам сделать это в Visual Studio?

Comment: @user7860670,  а как это сделать в VS?

Comment: Запускаете обычную отладку (Local Windows Debugger) и смотрите стек вызовов.

Comment: @user7860670 Обязательно ли при получении стека нужно указывать исходники, или как-то можно обойтись только pdb файлами? https://imgur.com/a/7PzHPYr

Comment: Там же написано - Можно посмотреть дизассемблированный код...

Comment: @user7860670 Вроде разобрался, спасибо. А можно как-то записать все события или историю изменения стека во время выполнения программы, вместо того что-бы бесконечно нажимать F11. Или выполнять все инструкции автоматически до следующего вызова?

Comment: Можно попробовать воспользоваться профайлером CPU. При просмотре результатов можно показать стек вызовов.

Comment: Получится что-то типа https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Cnb.png

Comment: @user7860670 а как сделать так же? Я попытался через Alt-F2 -> Инструментирование, но мне выдало только маленькую часть вызываемых функций. https://imgur.com/a/f3Cl1VR

Comment: Для профайлера CPU нажать на кнопку с шестеренкой и в настройках указать повышенную частоту опроса.

Comment: @user7860670 Установил максимальную частоту, но функции все так же не отображаются https://imgur.com/a/2HZtnte https://imgur.com/a/DXcrK7X

Comment: Наверное выставлен флаг Just my code https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6q2g.png